# Is there a way to disable WAC String for a specific link (ex. Tracking Link) with AMPscript or otherwise?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, web-analytics-connector

A client recently went live with a Commerce Cloud website / Marketing Cloud integration. Marketing Cloud is sending a Shipping Confirmation triggered email.

The tracking link in the Shipping Confirmation email won't resolve properly because of the WAC string.

Is there a way to disable the WAC string for a specific link using AMPscript or by any other method? Any other potential workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Here's a workaround to [prevent the addition of WAC parameters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317288&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) using AMPscript:

```
%%[ 
var @URL, @Link
Set @URL = "http://www.salesforce.com" 

Set @Link = Concat('<a href=',@URL,' alias="Link">Link Test</a>') 
]%% 

%%=v(@Link)=%%
```

Comment: Seems like there should be double-quotes around the href value.  And the v() function isn't necessary inside the concat().

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I literally copied and pasted from that "knowledge" article

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I just tested both solutions with or without the v() function and double or single quotes and both resulted in the exact same output.

Comment: No shade on your post, just calling it out.

Comment: Thanks guys! I was having trouble getting this to work, but figured it out. I just wanted to share on here in case any other AMPscript noobs come across this post.

IF you are pulling in your link from a DE like I am (%%TrackingURL%%), then setting the URL should look like this:

Set @URL = TrackingURL

(no quotes or percent signs)

I'm sure this is obvious to you two, but that took me a little while to figure out.