# Suppress specified links within emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I am looking to suppress a specified AMPscript personalization string link within the body of one of my emails. It's `%%view_email_url%%` that I don't want to be tracked. I tried RedirectTo and other options but nothing had worked on the back end. I am wondering if there is a way I am missing that someone could shine light upon.

If anyone has any other questions I can clarify.

Comment: Use Base64Decode to the view_email_url and encode it. This way salesforce doesnt know its a link actually -> no tracking involved

Comment: Have you tried this method? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314602&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 0):

This may be similar to the answer here about [disabling WAC parameters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284566/marketing-cloud-is-there-a-way-to-disable-wac-string-for-a-specific-link-ex/284569#284569). You can use the method described by user3274635 to [Stop a link from being tracked in a Marketing Cloud email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314602&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

```
%%[
set @viewEmailUrl = view_email_url
set @link = Concat('<a href="', @viewEmailUrl, '">Name of Link</a>')
]%%
%%=v(@link)=%%
```

Comment: Tried this and didn't work. view_email_url is a personalization string so it generates a link. Somehow have to generate it and then output using ampscript.