# Using RedirectTo() with an #anchor on the URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

SFMC automatically appends tracking information to our URLs at time of send. For example:

https://mywebsite.com

Becomes:

https://mywebsite.com?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_medium=email

Is it possible to append an anchor to the end of this URL to drop a user on a specific part of the page?

E.g. https://mywebsite.com?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_medium=email#page-anchor

It doesn't work for us to append the anchor on the base URL. Once tracking is appended after the pound (#) the anchor does not work.

Comment: To my knowledge with the analytics tracking being appended on, there is no way to add anchor tags. This is because in the OOO, the analytics stuff is added to the URLs at the very end of the AMPscript processing after all other actions are complete.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely hacky, but it has worked for me in the past. You'll need to open a ticket with SFMC Support to request an update to your WAC string, so that the very last parameter name in your query string can be used your very last [Additional Email Attribute](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5). So if you already have and use 5 `AdditionalEmailAttribute`'s, then this solution won't work.

Hypothetically let's say you already use 4, then the 5th would be added by SFMC support and could have a parameter name of "anchor". Then in your AdditionalEmailAttribute5 input in the email properties area, you can add your anchor, with the hashtag (#page-anchor in this example).

So your final url parameter would look like:

```
&anchor=%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%
```

and would resolve to:

```
&anchor=#page-anchor
```

This needs to be at the very end of the WAC string and the very end of the url overall, or else it will not work. Be sure to test thoroughly by sending "live" emails to yourself (as opposed to test sends), so the WAC will be appended. This solution may not work in every case an anchor is needed, especially if there are extra redirects happening on the page you are linking to.

Comment: UPDATE: you can update your own WAC string within Parameter manger

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce is aware of this, and I have been told a fix will be implemented, allowing you to use RedirectTo with an anchor tag in near future. Currently, you can have tracking parameters appended correctly with an anchor tag at the end, if you use standard links without RedirectTo, or use the dirty hack of jake314159

Comment: Looking forward to the solution! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can [prevent the additional of Web Analytics Connector (WAC)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284566/marketing-cloud-is-there-a-way-to-disable-wac-string-for-a-specific-link-ex/284569#284569) for that specific link and manually add the anchor and tracking.

```
%%[ set @URL = "https://mywebsite.com?utm_campaign=xxx&utm_medium=email#page-anchor" 

Set @Link = Concat('<a href=',@URL,' alias="Link">Link Test</a>') 
]%% 

%%=v(@Link)=%%
```

Comment: Hi, but i noticed that this stops tracking the click activity for this url.  Is there a work around for this?