# Is it possible to prevent parameter strings configured in Parameter Manager from being applied to individual links

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, hyperlink

We have a set of parameters configured in Parameter Manager that are applied to all links in our emails from that BU. Is it possible to selectively prevent those parameters from being applied to a URL?

Comment: Yes: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/284569/5202

Comment: Thanks Adam! That's exactly what I was after.

Comment: @EazyE - Yes, that's exactly what I was after and is the same as that provided by Adam in the previous comment. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment and linked question (Thanks Adam!):

Yes. Here's a workaround to prevent the addition of WAC parameters using AMPscript:

```
var @URL, @Link
Set @URL = "http://www.salesforce.com" 

Set @Link = Concat('<a href=',@URL,' alias="Link">Link Test</a>') 
]%% 

%%=v(@Link)=%%
```